# Model to LazyMap

Tags: dictionary, groovy, deserialization

How do I convert/deserialize these models

```
public class AccessCredentials {
    String userName = ''
    String password = ''
    LoginOptions loginOptions = new LoginOptions()
}

public class LoginOptions {
    String partnerId = ''
    String applicationId = ''
}
```

into a LazyMap like :

```
[ 
    userName : userName, 
    password : password,
    loginOptions : [
        partnerId : partnerId, 
        applicationId : applicationId
    ]
]
```

Comment: what did you try? i don't see any problem with such simple convertision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind).  E.g.

```
@Grab('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.4')
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

class AccessCredentials {
    String userName = 'Between The Buried And Me'
    String password = 'Alaska'
    LoginOptions loginOptions = new LoginOptions()
}

class LoginOptions {
    String partnerId = 'Colors'
    String applicationId = 'The Great Misdirect'
}

def mapper = new ObjectMapper()
assert mapper.convertValue(new AccessCredentials(), Map) == ['userName':'Between The Buried And Me', 'password':'Alaska', 'loginOptions':['partnerId':'Colors', 'applicationId':'The Great Misdirect']]
```

Comment: Nice! Any simple way without external libraries?

Comment: @Opal I never bothered.  jackson is most probably already a transitive dep in many web-facing projects.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this if you're looking for a quick hack

```
def objectMapper(o) {
    o.class.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }.collectEntries {
      switch(o."$it.name".class.name) {
          case ~/^java\..*/:
          case ~/^javax\..*/:
          case ~/^com\.sun\..*/:
          case ~/^sun\..*/:
              return [(it.name):o."$it.name"]
          default:
              return [(it.name):objectMapper(o."$it.name")]
      }

    }
}

objectMapper(new AccessCredentials())
```

Though the problem with quick hacks is you forget they were quick when they break later on, and are just left with a hack ;-)